# How to use mediapipe to detect static image in ios

Tags: ios, image, mediapipe

i can run the mediapipe example ios app,but i have a question is :How to use mediapipe to detect static image in ios. if u how to do ,please tell me ,think u

```
///this is a demo for check face static image 
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"faceImage.jpeg"];
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:faceImage];
bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height);
bgView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view insertSubview:bgView aboveSubview:self.liveView];

UIImageView *bgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
bgView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(bgView.frame) + 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
[self.view insertSubview:bgView1 aboveSubview:self.liveView];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:faceImage.CGImage];
///but this function not work
mediapipe::Packet packet = [self.mediapipeGraph imagePacketWithPixelBuffer:buffer];

mediapipe::Image image = packet.Get<mediapipe::Image>();
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBufferOut = image.GetCVPixelBufferRef();
bgView1.image = [self convert:pixelBufferOut];
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve it，if u meet same problem , look this:https://github.com/lxm1799/FaceMediapipe